Minimum Security Role to view WorkFlow Run History on production env without the ability to edit
We have a production environment inside our Power Platform admin center. The environment contains 1 custom solution, the solution has 3 workflows. And when one of the workflows fails it send an email to the IT support. now we want to grant the IT support account a read-only permission to be able to view the Run-History of the failed workflows without the ability to edit the workflows or create a new flow inside the production environment? will the Basic User be sufficient for such a case? if not then what is the minimum-security role needed?

Thanks

As far as I know this is not possible. The run history of an individual flow is only readable for those users who can access the flow (co-owners or run-only users). Run-only users can only see their own runs. To see all runs, users must be given co-owner permissions to the relevant flow.
This is not a question of the security role. Even Power Platform administrators (System Administrators) do not have access to the run history of flows of which they are not owners.
